# Data writes over after realloc

Tags: c, realloc

I a function that allows you to add question to a game. I use realloc to increase the memory so i can store more questions.

Script:

```
struct Question* AddQuestions(int* amountQuest){
    struct Question* questionsLocation = NULL;
    int startQuestion = 0;//How many question from before.
    int amount;
    if (*amountQuest > 0){
        startQuestion = *amountQuest;
    }

    system("cls");
    printf("How many statement do you want to add? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &amount);
    printf("\n");

    *amountQuest = amount + startQuestion;//Total amount of questions
    //Realloc or allocate new block if null
    questionsLocation = (struct Question*)realloc(questionsLocation,*amountQuest * sizeof(struct Question));

    if (questionsLocation != NULL){ // Check if allocating worked
        //Add questions
        for (int i = startQuestion; i < *amountQuest; i++){//Starts att startQuestion so I don't override the old question.
            printf("Statement %d: ", i + 1);
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(questionsLocation[i].question, 200, stdin);

            printf("Dificulty: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &questionsLocation[i].difficult);

            printf("Right answer [1 = true / 0 = false] : ");
            scanf_s("%d", &questionsLocation[i].rightAnswer);

            printf("\n");
        }

        return questionsLocation;
    }
    else{
        printf("Problem occurred, try again");
        fflush(stdin);
        getchar();
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

When I add the new questions the old get override.
Image: When I add the first questions without problem
[image: First image where everything works]

Image: When I add more questions and I get problem.
[image: Second image where it fails]

Comment: Something tells me knowing everything about `struct Question` would assist people in viewing your code. Post it please, ideally in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also see nothing that *previously* allocates to `questionsLocation`. In fact, `struct Question* questionsLocation = NULL;` is the only prior encounter, which is valid to send to `realloc`, but has no prior content, so I don't see how anything is being lost or overwritten from nothing. And stop `fflush`-ing `stdin`. It isn't standard.

Comment: Show us the code that calls `AddQuestions`. Also, please show the `Question` struct.

Comment: a note: `fflush(stdin);` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: `startQuestion` is not a static variable. It won't contain the number from before, it will be set to `0` every time you call the function.

Comment: Consider copying your input and output as *text* into your question. The images do not add anything useful, and are hard to read anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't attempt to preserve the earlier questions. It always calls `realloc()` with a `NULL` pointer, resulting in a brand new allocation:

```
struct Question* questionsLocation = NULL;
/* ...there are no assignments to questionsLocation here... */
questionsLocation = (struct Question*)realloc(questionsLocation,
                                      *amountQuest * sizeof(struct Question));
```

To preserve the data, you need to hold on to the pointer you got from `realloc()` and use it next time you are reallocating memory.

One way to do this is to change the function to take `questionsLocation` as an argument:

```
struct Question* AddQuestions(int* amountQuest, struct Question* questionsLocation) {
    ...
    questionsLocation = (struct Question*)realloc(questionsLocation, ...);
    ...
    return questionsLocation;
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
int amountQuest = 0;
struct Question* questionsLocation = NULL;
...
questionsLocation = AddQuestion(&amountQuest, questionsLocation);
```

(For clarity, I did not include any error checking. You might want to add some.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `questionsLocation` and `startQuestion` to be `static` so they'll keep their values from one call to the next.

```
static struct Question* questionsLocation = NULL;
static int startQuestion = 0;//How many question from before.
```

However, a better approach in general is for your function to receive these values as parameters.

```
struct Question* AddQuestions(int* amountQuest, structQuestion*questionsLocation, int startQuestion){
```

Comment: Without an explanation of pitfalls associated with `static` variables, are you sure this is good advice?

Answer (score 0):

Right way to realloc() is

The size should be able to accomodate both your previous questions as well as the new questions. For Eg:

```
n = num_of_old_questions + num_of_new_questions;

struct Question *temp = realloc(questionsLocation, sizeof(struct Question) * n); 

if(temp != NULL)
{
  questionsLocation = temp;
}
```

If `realloc()` fails then you will be loosing your original pointer data also so it is better to use `temp` for reallocation and check the return value before assigning it to the original pointer